# How to share stores between anonymous visitors?

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, svelte-store

I have a [single-page app](https://github.com/ziyuang/svelte-ktv) that works fine. Now the plan is to add another interface for mobile device users (e.g., an interface rendered conditionally for the visitors from mobile devices), such that when they interact with the interface, they will influence the app already opened in a PC browser. In my case, this may correspond to, that a mobile device user chooses a video source in his/her interface, and changes the video being played on the PC browser. I suppose this would be achievable if different visitors can share a `writable` store for the video source. I am aware of sveltekit, but I find it less obvious to structure the app especially when I have a `server.ts` providing the video contents. Any ideas?

**Update**: the comments are correct and I have implemented this with websocket. Thanks!

Comment: Do you really need to use stores like you are doing currently? It seems like you're using them as a lazy way to implement global UI state rather than for their intended purpose.

Comment: @IsaacCorbrey I am open to suggestions so can you hint me on how to correctly implement a "global UI state"? I do intend to use the store as a global UI state.

Comment: 2 app instances cann't communicate together by simply using javascript (writable store). You will need another type of communication like websocket if you want live update.

Comment: @ziyuang in short, you don't. UI state should be local, and should spend on more meaningful data states. Global UI state is bad.